# gulp-sass import doesn't rebase the right images' url when used relative path

Tags: css, sass, gulp

For example, I have a project like this:

[image]

If common.css imports an image from `'/src/css/imgs'` folder and
common.css is imported by `'src/css/channel/index.scss'`.
But after transformed by `gulp-sass`, `index.scss` is transformed to `'dist/css/channel/index.css'`, the image's path in `index.css` file
does not rebase to `'/dist/css/imgs'` folder.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rebase . This looks to me like the exact thing you are looking for.

Gulp won't change your paths automatically unless you are using some sort of plugin like the one above?

So you can just add something like this to your gulp file:

```
gulp.src('/src/css/imgs/*').pipe(rebase('/dist/css/imgs'));
```